# Naming convention for tagged template functions

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, tagged-templates

Tagged template functions aren't *normal* functions in the same way that constructor functions aren't normal functions.  They should never be called apart from in a *special* way.  Constructors, with a `new`, tagging functions with an interpolated string literal.

We have a convention that constructors must be in Pascal Case so it is clear to the caller that it's a constructor.

1. Is there a similar convention for tagging functions?
2. If not, would enforcing that they have a trailing underscore be ambiguous to any other convention?

```js
function tagger_(s, name, food) {  
  return `${s[0]}${name}${s[1]}${food}${s[2]}`
}

const name = 'Dave';
const food = 'ice-cream'
const message = tagger_`Hello World!  My name is ${name} and I like ${food} for dinner`;

console.log(message);
```

The argument for this not being a *normal* function is that the first argument isn't a string.

```js
const log = console.log;

function tagger_(s) {
    console.log(`Has raw property: ${!!s.raw}`);
}

tagger_(`Hello World!`);
tagger_`Hello World!`
```

Likewise the `s.raw` property contains the string, unescaped.  There would be no practical way to *spoof* this.  Even if one could, it would be very bad practice.

```js
function tagger_(s) {
    console.log(`s.raw: ${s.raw}`);
}

tagger_`This\nhas\tspecial characters`
```

**The Duck Typing Problem**

Whilst it may be possible to create a duck-typed object to pass into the method such that it won't fail immediately, the interface of the engune-generated object might extent (e.g. maybe an `escapedRaw` property is added).  This would mean anything calling the method as a normal function would break.

When we write a normal function were totally in control of it, this isn't the case here because the `s` parameter type isn't controlled by the writer if the function.

Comment: I don't think tagging functions are special. They have a distinctive signature, yes, but otherwise they really are normal functions. You can call them like any other function, you just have to pass the right arguments.

Comment: @Bergi They're special because the first argument is set to a special type.

Comment: @Bergi I've added a demo to highlight why I think it should be a special function.

Comment: @BanksySan — I think you're mistaken about the "non-string" argument.  `'foo' instanceof String` also returns false.

Comment: @BenBlank You're right.  I've removed it.

Comment: @BanksySan They need to be called with an array as the first argument, that's all. Maybe the array should be frozen and have a `.raw` property, but that's still normally achievable. (Unlike constructors, which need  `new`/`super()` or `Reflect.construct`)

Comment: @Bergi that still doesn't solve the problem.  `s.raw` is the string, unespaced.  I've added another demo.

Comment: @BanksySan Actually `s.raw` is an array, but regardless: I don't see the problem that you are talking about. Nothing prevents you from passing such values (made-up or not) to a tag function through a normal function call. Sure, passing invalid data would be a bad practice, but so is passing invalid values to any other function.

Comment: @BanksySan Consider `String.raw({raw:["This\\nhas\\tspecial characters"]})`.

Comment: @Bergi how would you construct `raw` in a non-horrible way?  Even it it's possible, wouldn't it be a horrible monkey patch?

Comment: @BanksySan What do you mean by "non-horrible way"? The raw value might come from a string literal, from a `String.raw` string, from a file reader or anywhere else.

Comment: @Bergi I mean that we can't guarantee that there won't me a change made in the language that could expose another, special features that's use.  Monkeying the object and calling it like a normal function would break if the tagging function used the new feature.

Comment: @BanksySan Well I guess that could be said about all functions expecting special objects :-) Finally, consider ``function tag(...args) { return String.raw(...args); } tag`…`;`` where `String.raw` is called like a normal function in a totally valid way.

Comment: @Bergi I've described the problem with duck-tying the object above.